# Install Flex without removing other packeges?

Tags: apt, software-installation, gcc

I tried to install ettercap tool but it stops with error "configure: error: flex was not found, please install" so i tried to install flex using 
$sudo apt-get install flex 
command but it reports to me this "The following packages will be REMOVED:
  dkms gcc gcc-4.6 libtool openvswitch-datapath-dkms" and I need openvswitch & gcc packages 
How I can install flex without removing other packeges??

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Can you edit your post to include the outputs of `apt-cache policy flex` and `dpkg -l dkms gcc gcc-4.6 openvswitch-datapath-dkms` please?

Answer (score 0):

I think your gcc is too old.  the apt package system prefers your software to be up-to-date.  do an 'apt-get update' then 'apt-get upgrade' OR try installing your flex software with the '--no-install-recommends' flag.  seems the upgrade in question requires uninstall then new install.